# multithreading in winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I’m writing a win forms that uses the report viewer for the creation of multiple PDF files. These PDF files are divided in 4 main parts, each part is responsible for the creation of a specific report. These processes are creating a minimum of 1 file up to the number of users (currently 50).

The program already exists using there 4 methods sequentially. For extra performance where the number of users is growing, I want to separate these methods from the mail process in 4 separate threads.

While I'm new to multithreading using C# I read a number of articles how to achieve this. The only thing I'm not sure of is which way I should start. As I read multiple blog posts I'm not sure if to use 4 separate threads, a thread pool or multiple background workers. (or should parallel programming be the best way?). Blog posts tell me if more than 3 threads use a thread pool, but on the other hand the tell me if using winforms, use the backgroundworker. Which option is best (and why)?

At the end my main thread has to wait for all processes to end before continuing.

Can someone tell me what's the best solution to my problem.

*** Extra information after edit ***

Which i forgot to tell (after i read al your comments and possible solutions). The methods share one "IEnumerable" only for reading. After firing the methods (that don't have to run sequentially), the methods trigger events for for sending status updates to the UI. I think triggering events is difficult if not impossible using separate threads so there should be some kind of callback function to report status updates while running.

some example in psuedo code.

```
 main()
 {
       private List<customclass> lcc = importCustomClass()

       export.CreatePDFKind1.create(lcc.First(), exportfolderpath, arg1)

       export.CreatePDFKind2.create(lcc, exportfolderpath)

       export.CreatePDFKind3.create(lcc.First(), exportfolderpath) 

       export.CreatePDFKind4.create(customclass2, exportfolderpath)
 } 

 namespace export
 {
     class CreatePDFKind1         
     {
        create(customclass cc, string folderpath)
        {
            do something;
            reportstatus(listviewItem, status, message)
        }
     }

     class CreatePDFKind2
     {
        create(IEnumerable<customclass> lcc, string folderpath)
        {
            foreach (var x in lcc)
            {
               do something;
               reportstatus(listviewItem, status, message)
            }
        }
     }

     etc.......
  }
```

Comment: People generally recommend a backgroundworker to keep the UI responsive while you do some long-running operation on another thread.  It's probably not the best choice here since you'll want multiple threads.  TPL might be the way to go.

Comment: If the four operations occur sequentially you only need one thread. In that case I would use a background worker.

Answer (score 5):

From the very basic picture you have described, I would use the [Task Paralell Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Shipped with .NET Framework 4.0+.

You talk about the 'best' option of using thread pools when spawning a *large*-to-medium number of threads. Dispite this being correct [the most efficent way of mangaing the resources], the TPL does all of this for you - without you having to worry about a thing. The TPL also makes the use of multiple threads and waiting on their completion a doddle too...

To do what you require I would use the **TPL** and [Continuations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx). A continuation not only allows you to create a flow of tasks but also handles your exceptions. This is a [great introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n) to the TPL. But to give you some idea...

You can start a TPL task using

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    // Do some work here...
});
```

Now to start a second task when an antecedent task finishes (in error or successfully) you can use the `ContinueWith` method

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Antecedant Task"));
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith(antTask => Console.WriteLine("Continuation..."));
```

So as soon as `task1` completes, fails or is cancelled `task2` 'fires-up' and starts running. Note that if `task1` had completed before reaching the second line of code `task2` would be scheduled to execute immediately. The `antTask` argument passed to the second lambda is a reference to the antecedent task. See [this link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for more detailed examples...

You can also pass continuations results from the antecedent task

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => 1)
    .ContinueWith(antTask => antTask.Result * 4)
    .ContinueWith(antTask => antTask.Result * 4)
    .ContinueWith(antTask =>Console.WriteLine(antTask.Result * 4)); // Prints 64.
```

Note. Be sure to read up on exception handling in the first link provided as this can lead a newcomer to TPL astray.

One last thing to look at in particular for what you want is child tasks. Child tasks are those which are created as `AttachedToParent`. In this case the continuation will not run until all child tasks have completed

```
TaskCreationOptions atp = TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SomeMethod() }, atp);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SomeOtherMethod() }, atp); 
}).ContinueWith( cont => { Console.WriteLine("Finished!") });
```

So in your case you would start your four tasks, then wait on their completion on the main thread.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `BackgroundWorker` is helpful if you need to interact with the UI with respect to your background process.  If you don't, then I wouldn't bother with it.  You can just start 4 `Task` objects directly:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>DoStuff()));
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>DoStuff2()));
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>DoStuff3()));
```

If you *do* need to interact with the UI; possibly by updating it to reflect when the tasks are finished, then I would suggest staring **one** `BackgroundWorker` and then using tasks again to process each individual unit of work.  Since there is some additional overhead in using a `BackgroundWorker` I would avoid starting lots of them if you can avoid it.

```
BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
bgw.DoWork += (_, args) =>
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoStuff()));
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoStuff2()));
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoStuff3()));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
};
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (_, args) => updateUI();
bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

You could of course use just `Task` methods to do all of this, but I still find BackgroundWorkers a bit simpler to work with for the simpler cases.  Using .NEt 4.5 you could use `Task.WhenAll` to run a continuation in the UI thread when all 4 tasks finished, but doing that in 4.0 wouldn't be quite as simple.

Comment: For the update of the UI, why not use a contiuation, using the `TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` and then pass this to the continuation which will allow you ti update the UI...

Comment: @Killercam It's not quite as trivial with 4.0 if you have multiple tasks.  What you really need is `WhenAll`, and that was added in 4.5 (and if you have 4.5 you're probably better off just using async/await on it).  As I said, it's *doable*, just not quite as straightforward.  Dealing with progress reporting using the TPL is also less simple than with a BGW.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information it's impossible to tell. The fact that they're in four separate methods doesn't make much of a difference if they're accessing the same resources. The PDF file for example. If you're having trouble understanding what I mean you should post some of the code for each method and I'll go into a little more detail.

Since the number of "parts" you have is fixed it won't make a big difference whether you use separate threads, background workers or use a thread pool. I'm not sure why people are recommending background workers. Most likely because it's a simpler approach to multithreading and more difficult to screw up.